# Cannot import Selenium2library on Robot Framework : error (import file not found)

Tags: python, macos, pycharm, robotframework

I cant not add Selenium2Library, i get this error (import file not found)

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation     Simple example using SeleniumLibrary.
Library           Selenium2Library
```

Comment: The Selenium2Library is old. Try installing `robotframework-seleniumlibrary` and then using `SeleniumLibrary` in your settings.

Comment: I have this on pip list : 
`robotframework-selenium2library 1.8.0`     
`robotframework-seleniumlibrary  4.1.1.dev1`

Comment: You don't need both. You should remove robot-selenium2library 1.8.0. that is over 3 years old.

Comment: i have this :
![Valid XHTML](https://imgur.com/Py7VRCh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have Selenium2Library installed by using

```
pip list
```

In case Selenium2Library is not displayed in the list, then download the library by using:

```
pip install --upgrade robotframework-selenium2library
```

I assume you have pip installed, If not this is the procedure:

1. Download [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) to a folder on your computer.
2. Open a command prompt and navigate to the folder containing get-pip.py.
3. Run the following command: `python get-pip.py`

Answer (score 1):

Try installation as above @Alberto below or visit [for installation documentation](https://github.com/robotframework/SeleniumLibrary#installation)

SeleniumLibrary documents says also following:

> NOTE: Selenium2Library has been renamed to SeleniumLibrary since version 3.0. Nowadays Selenium2Library is just a thin wrapper to SeleniumLibrary that eases with transitioning to the new project. See SeleniumLibrary and Selenium2Library project pages for more information.

Answer (score 0):

have you installed the selenium2library library? 
If not, try installing it with this command:

`pip install robotframework-selenium2library`

Answer (score 0):

Please verify whether you have performed the following before executing your code.

BEFORE -  robotframework-selenium2library is installed

```
(myblog) 05:53 PM##~/bins/projects/PycharmProjects/blog::>conda activate rf1
(rf1) 05:54 PM##~/bins/projects/PycharmProjects/blog::>pip list
Package                 Version            
----------------------- -------------------
certifi                 2018.11.29         
chardet                 3.0.4              
colorama                0.4.1              
configparser            4.0.2              
crayons                 0.3.0              
et-xmlfile              1.0.1              
idna                    2.8                
jdcal                   1.4.1              
openpyxl                3.0.1              
pip                     19.3.1             
robotframework          3.1.2              
robotframework-excellib 2.0.0              
setuptools              41.6.0.post20191030
wheel                   0.33.6
```

AFTER - robotframework-selenium2library is installed,
**notice that 3 packages are installed**,eventhough you have just installed one package,

**robotframework-selenium2library,
robotframework-seleniumlibrary,selenium**

```
(rf1) 05:54 PM##~/bins/projects/PycharmProjects/blog::>pip install robotframework-selenium2library
Collecting robotframework-selenium2library
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1c/f1/612f9aa29f33b25a1034749dde67dfbf6de9b297709d06df71f9bfabfc81/robotframework_selenium2library-3.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting robotframework-seleniumlibrary>=3.0.0
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/dc/69/c20102b9e336b32eb813966ee2b98b6de1b1249032ebb3ce3cabcf26fac7/robotframework_seleniumlibrary-4.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting selenium>=3.8.1
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/80/d6/4294f0b4bce4de0abf13e17190289f9d0613b0a44e5dd6a7f5ca98459853/selenium-3.141.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: robotframework>=3.0.4 in /Users/apachemain/bins/anaconda/envs/rf1/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from robotframework-seleniumlibrary>=3.0.0->robotframework-selenium2library) (3.1.2)
Collecting urllib3
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b4/40/a9837291310ee1ccc242ceb6ebfd9eb21539649f193a7c8c86ba15b98539/urllib3-1.25.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: urllib3, selenium, robotframework-seleniumlibrary, robotframework-selenium2library
Successfully installed robotframework-selenium2library-3.0.0 robotframework-seleniumlibrary-4.1.0 selenium-3.141.0 urllib3-1.25.7
(rf1) 05:54 PM##~/bins/projects/PycharmProjects/blog::>pip list
Package                         Version            
------------------------------- -------------------
certifi                         2018.11.29         
chardet                         3.0.4              
colorama                        0.4.1              
configparser                    4.0.2              
crayons                         0.3.0              
et-xmlfile                      1.0.1              
idna                            2.8                
jdcal                           1.4.1              
openpyxl                        3.0.1              
pip                             19.3.1             
robotframework                  3.1.2              
robotframework-excellib         2.0.0              
robotframework-selenium2library 3.0.0              
robotframework-seleniumlibrary  4.1.0              
selenium                        3.141.0            
setuptools                      41.6.0.post20191030
urllib3                         1.25.7             
wheel                           0.33.6             
(rf1) 05:54 PM##~/bins/projects/PycharmProjects/blog::>
```

CODE

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation     This example demonstrates how to use current library
Library      Selenium2Library

*** Test Cases ***
Run Sample Selenium Case
    Open Browser   http://google.com
    Set Window Size    1920    1080
    ${title}=    Get Title
    Should Be Equal    Google    ${title}
    [Teardown]    Close Browser
```

**OUTPUT**

```
(rf1) 06:02 PM##~/bins/projects/PycharmProjects/blog::>robot sam.robot 
==============================================================================
Sam :: This example demonstrates how to use current library                   
==============================================================================
Run Sample Selenium Case                                              | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sam :: This example demonstrates how to use current library           | PASS |
1 critical test, 1 passed, 0 failed
1 test total, 1 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
Output:  /Users/apachemain/bins/projects/PycharmProjects/blog/output.xml
Log:     /Users/apachemain/bins/projects/PycharmProjects/blog/log.html
Report:  /Users/apachemain/bins/projects/PycharmProjects/blog/report.html
```